# How do I get Java to parse and format a date/time with the same time zone? I keep getting the local timezone

Tags: java, timezone, utc

My application keeps all Java Date's in UTC. Parsing them is easy, but when I print them out, the display shows the computer's local time zone, and I want to show it as UTC.

Example code:

```
String sample = "271210 200157 UTC";
SimpleDateFormat dfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy HHmmss Z");
Date result = dfmt.parse(sample);
System.out.printf("%tc\n", result);
```

the result is

Mon Dec 27 15:01:57 EST 2010

What I want is

Mon Dec 27 20:01:57 UTC 2010

Clearly I have to set some Locale and TimeZone values, but I don't see where to put them.
Thanks
Pat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [set the time zone](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) for the DateFormat:

```
  dfmt.setTimeZone(timeZone);
```

Also, you do not want to print the Date object itself, but again use the DateFormat

```
  String formattedDate = dfmt.format(result);
```

Comment: Thanks.This code on the output side does exactly what I want. <br>       SimpleDateFormat outfmt = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");<br>
        outfmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));<br>
        String formattedDate = outfmt.format(result);<br>
        System.out.println(formattedDate);<br>

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid java.util.Date

The old java.util.Date, .Calendar, and SimpleDateFormat classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Among the many problems is the fact that a java.util.Date object:

- Has a time zone buried deep inside
- Ignores that time zone for most practical purposes
- Has a `toString` method implementation that applies the JVM’s current default time zone when generating the String representation of its internal UTC date-time value.

So to a naïve programmer, the Date object seems to have a time zone but is actually always is UTC (just a 64-bit integer inside, a count from [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date))).

## Bad Format

The format of your input string is clumsy. In particular, using two digits for the year is problematic.

If you have any control, I strongly suggest changing it. The first choice is to follow the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## Joda-Time & java.time

Use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package built into Java 8 (and inspired by Joda-Time).

Unlike a java.util.Date, a DateTime object in Joda-Time clearly understands its own assigned time zone. If you omit the time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is assigned. I recommend always specifying the desired time zone.

Both Joda-Time and java.time use ISO 8601 formats by default for both generating and parsing String representations of date-time values.

In Joda-Time 2.7…

```
String input = "271210 200157 UTC";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "ddMMyy HHmmss z" ).withZoneUTC();
DateTime dateTimeUtc = formatter.parseDateTime( input );
```

Easy to adjust time zone. For fun, let's move that UTC value into Québec time zone.

```
DateTime dateTimeMontréal = dateTimeUtc.withZone( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) );
String output = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).print( dateTimeMontréal );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input : " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc : " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeMontréal : " + dateTimeMontréal );
System.out.println( "output : " + output );
```

```
input : 271210 200157 UTC
dateTimeUtc : 2010-12-27T20:01:57.000Z
dateTimeMontréal : 2010-12-27T15:01:57.000-05:00
output : lundi 27 décembre 2010 15 h 01 EST
```