# How to parse time in correct timezone java?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am parsing a time stamp which is a string as follows:

```
Date receivedDateObj = new Date();
String inputDate = "Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                try {
                    System.out.println(inputDate);
                    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                    receivedDateObj = formatter.parse(inputDate);
                }catch (ParseException e) {

                }
System.out.println(receivedDateObj);
```

The date gets parsed correctly but when I print the date, it prints the following:

```
Fri Dec 31 18:59:59 EST 1999
```

How do I get it to print GMT instead of EST? Why is the timezone not getting set despite me setting it using the following?

```
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get Java to parse and format a date/time with the same time zone? I keep getting the local timezone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551543/how-do-i-get-java-to-parse-and-format-a-date-time-with-the-same-time-zone-i-kee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` object has no timezone information.  It's a fixed instant in time.  Dumping to the console just uses `Date.toString();` which uses the JVM's timezone to perform the format.  If you want to convert your fixed instant in time back to a 'human' representation in a particular timezone, just send it back through your formatter the other way.

```
System.out.println(formatter.format(receivedDateObj));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the joda time librairy. This API contains some beautifull classes to achieve what you're willing to do : DateTimeFormat, DateTimeZone... In my opinion it's the best date API in java.

The javadoc is quite exhaustive and many examples are present on the web (including stackoverflow of course).

sources :

http://www.joda.org/joda-time/

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html